# Is it possible to know or get an reasonable upper bound on the number of solutions to an $2$D Polynomial equation ($n$D)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, upper-lower-bounds, multivariate-polynomial

I have two arbitrary but finite order $2$D polynomial functions $P_1(\vec x)$ and $P_2(\vec x)$, both on the domain $[-1,1]^2$. If I construct an algebraic equation $P_1(\vec x)^2 + P_2(\vec x)^2 = 0$, and know that there exists at least one real solution, is there a way to know more about possible other real solutions. Is there some theory of algebra (possibly Galois theory) that allows me to determine if there exist more real solutions? Mind you, I do not care what the real solutions are, I only wish to know if there are more than one. If this is not possible does there exist some way of putting a useful upper bound on the number of real solutions? Additionally, if I had $n$ polynomials is there a way to accomplish the same thing in $n$D. In other words I want to know if
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n P_k^2(\vec x) = 0
$$
has only one real solution or more than one. In this case $\vec x \: \in [-1,1]^n$.

Comment: Much too vague. Please [edit] to clarify. There must be more conditions on the polynomial to say anything useful. The polynomial equation $x+y=0$ has infinitely many real integral solutions ...

Comment: You can use [Sturm's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem#:~:text=The%20length%20of%20the%20Sturm,most%20the%20degree%20of%20P.&text=This%20number%20of%20sign%20variations,such%20that%20a%20%3C%20b) for the number of real solutions.

Comment: @EthanBolker I clarified the kind of polynomial I have.

Comment: Better. But each term in that sum of squares must be $0$ for their sum to be $0$, so you are really asking about the simultaneous roots of two polynomials. Try some examples in two and three dimensions. You may find the intersection of surfaces in space, so infinitely many solutions.  Have you looked at simple examples?

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, that is actually by design! The question is equivalently how do you know you have more than one shared solutions to two polynomial equations.

Comment: @EthanBolker The question has been even further clarified.